# Correct alternative to a 'mutable function' in c++

Tags: c++, mutable

I often have a problem with const correctness when wrapping algorithms in classes in c++.  I feel that I want a mutable function, although this is not allowed.  Can anyone advise me how to implement classes such as the one that follows?

The following is the code that I *want* to write.

- The function run() should not be a
  const function because it changes the
  data.
- The function get_result()  should
  be a constant function (as far as the user is concerned) because it returns
  the data.

However, if the user requests the result without calling run(), I want the get_result() function to run the algorithm.  This breaks the const correctness because I have a const function calling a non-const function.

```
class operate_on_data
{
  std::vector<double> m_data;  // the data to modify
  bool m_completed;  // check to see if the function run() has been called
public:
  operate_on_data(std::vector<double> data)
    : m_data(data), m_completed(false) {}  //initialise
  void run() //I don't want this function to be const  
  {
    //The algorithm goes here - it alters m_data.
    m_completed = true;  //the algorithm has been run
  }
  std::vector<double> get_result() const //I want this function to be const
  {
    /*The following breaks const correctness because 
      I am calling a non-const function from a const function
      - but this feels like the right thing to do ... */ 
    if (!m_completed) run();  //run the algorithm if it has not run already
    return m_data; //return
  }
};
```

The only way I have been I have managed to compile the above class is to either

- make run() const, and make m_data and m_completed mutable.  This works but is conceptually wrong because run() demonstrably changes data.
- make get_result() not a constant function.  This seems wrong too, for the user would expect this function to be a simple return, and therefore constant.
- Put the run() function into the get_result() const function and make the data variables mutable.

My understanding was that the mutable keyword was designed for the third of these options, where the implementation requires data to be changed but the user reasonably expects a simple return and therefore const function.

However, I don't want to do this final option because I want the user to be able to choose exactly when they change the data.  There is a chance that they will forget to call run(), however, and so I want to force the algorithm if they request the result without calling run(). I feel like a want to make run() mutable - but I'm not allowed to.

What is the correct way to write such a class?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to call run() from the constructor?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, run() can sometimes be expensive both in time and memory.  I want the user to be construct the class and call the method later.  In particular, I sometimes pass a small class over a cluster, and return  small result. I want the expensive run() command to be independent of these two function calls.

Comment: If run() can be expensive both in time and memory, then you shouldn't worry about forcing the user to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*make run() const, and make m_data and m_completed mutable. This works but is conceptually wrong because run() demonstrably changes data.*

Not true, actually.  The *variables* within your class are, in fact, altered but you could never, ever demonstrate this.  Calling run() does not change anything that the user is able to retrieve from your class's interface.  If you can't retrieve any information about such a change then you can't possibly demonstrate that change.  This is more than a semantic issue, it speaks directly to the whole point of the 'mutable' keyword.

The 'mutable' keyword is greatly misunderstood.

That said, though with the minimally given information I have I might do it the above way, I'm not recommending it.  There's almost certainly a better method that would be apparent given a larger view of your problem.

The other method I might use is what you're apparently set on avoiding: force the user to call run() before using get_data().  To tell the truth though, this is a really suboptimal method too.  Perhaps more so.

Edit:

If you do decide to use the mutable method then I'd suggest some changes.  Having a function called 'run()' that is const and returns nothing of interest would be quite confusing.  This function should certainly be non-const.  Thus, what I would do, given a decision to do it this way already, is have run() call a const and private function that has the behavior of the current 'run()' function, which is also referred to by get_data() under the specified conditions.

Comment: I think the consensus is to make it an exception but I do like your solution Noah.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah.  I certainly would not base my decisions on SO consensus.  This case is no different.  The 'correct' answer here is almost certainly to kill this object of yours; it's not doing anything interesting.  My post is simply to explain why your, and others here, analysis of the const/mutable issue is flawed.

Comment: Yes, thank you Noah,  I think I need a redesign taking on board kos' answer too.  Your edit does solve what I was originally trying to do, though.

Comment: You can use the type system to ensure and communicate to the user that they must call run() first.  Make "run()" a free function which returns an instance of a class representing the cooked (run-upon) data.  Then make the operate_on_data class take this instance in its constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Some abstract remarks which may help you clarify things:

- `const` methods are those which don't modify the conceptual "state" of an objects,
- non-`const` method are those which do.
- Additionally, `mutable` fields are those which are per-object, but not considered a part of the object's conceptual `state` (like some cached values which are evaluated lazily and remembered).

The problem might be that `operate_on_data` may not really be a well-defined class. What is an object of class "operate_on_data"? What is the "state" of this object? What is not? This sounds awkward (at least to me) - and awkward-sounding description of some design may indicate counter-intuitive design.

My thought is that you're keeping the different concepts of an "operation" and an "operation result" in one strange class, which leads to confusion.

Comment: I think of operate_on_data is a functor.  I often add a void operator()() {run();} function too.  I want to be able to control when the functor is run, and when the data is returned.

Comment: A "functor" - as I've always understood it - is an object which can be called to run an operation Doesn't matter if the "logical parameters" are passed as fields of functor instance or as parameters to `operator()`. But a functor is not responsible for keeping the calculation result - at least I've never stumbled upon a convention in which it would, which makes perfect sense. The "operation" is one thing, the "operation result" is another.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is a semantic, not a syntactic one.

Requesting the result without calling `run()` first is an error, in my eyes, and should result in an exception.

If it is *not* an error and should indeed be possible, I see no sense in having `run()` in the first place, so just drop it and do all the work in the (non-const) `get_result()`.

Comment: Thank you DevSolar.  I take your point with dropping the run() function but for me Noah's edit works out best.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it an error (part of the interface) to get the result prior to running the algorithm. Then you separate the work from the results, allowing both to properly indicate their constness. The get method can throw if you attempt to call it prior to running the algorithm to indicate to the client they're doing something wrong.

Comment: Many thanks, but is there no way to do it internally? It is clear what the user did wrong, I feel I should be able to correct this mistake myself. Crashing the users program seems a bit drastic.

Comment: Throwing an exception as documented in the API is **very much** different from "crashing the users program"!

Comment: @DevSolar, this is true but forcing the user to write a try-catch for something so simple seems a bit sledgehammer approach.

Comment: @Tom Trying to guess what the user wanted to do isn't a good idea. Consider what would happen if the compiler thought I was missing a `;` in my C++ program but instead it was a different problem entirely. If you make the interface require that the user go through a known API you're perfectly allowed to throw an exception when they violate it.

Comment: Many thanks Mark B.  Your right of course, but for this particular case I go with Noah's edit. I think I need a redesign (taking on board Kos' point) but in the mean time Noah solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

If `get_result()` may actually change data, it is not const.  If you want it to be const, don't call `run()` but rather throw an exception.

You should use `mutable` for cached data, i.e. things that do not change the state of your instance and are only stored for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you Sven.  For my particular case Noah's distinction and edit works best for me. All the best

Answer (score 1):

The concept of const is up to the implementation of the class; what's important is the logical semantics, not field level / function level constness. Therefore, if one needs to call a non-const method from const, simply const cast. I prefer:

```
void X::foo(  ) const {
      X & self = const_cast<X &>(*this);
      self.bar( ); //"bar" non-const function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I ever come into that position, I'd probably throw an exception.

However, you *may* get away with

```
if (!m_completed) (const_cast <operate_on_data *> (this))->run();
```

However, if `get_result` is then called on an instance of `operate_on_data` that has actually been defined to be `const`, you enter lala-land.

Comment: @downvoter: If I advised anything, then to throw an exception, i.e. fix the interface. Apart from that, I gave a minimally invasive code example to make what the OP wanted work and listed the condition where it breaks. How is that an unhelpful comment, bad advice even?

Comment: Why it is bad advice has already been stated within your post.

Comment: Thank you dennycrane. I think you are with the consensus with throwing an exception.  For the alternative, I like Noahs edit of putting a run() const as a private function and calling that.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that `run()` changes in the object is `m_completed` then it's fine to declare `m_completed mutable` and `run()` `const`.  If `run()` changes other things, then calling `get_result()` will also change those other things, meaning `get_result()` should definitely not be `const`.

However, to round out the discussion, you will notice that the STL containers each have two `begin()` functions and two `end()` functions.  One `begin()` and one `end()` function will return mutable iterators, while the other `begin()` and `end()` functions will return `const_iterator`s.

It is in fact possible to overload `run()` with a `const` and non-`const` version.  Then `get_result()` will call the `const` version of `run()` because it will be considered the only legal option:

```
class operate_on_data
{
    std::vector<double> m_data;
    bool m_completed;
public:
    operate_on_data(std::vector<double> data)
        : m_data(data), m_completed(false) { }
    void run()
    {
       //The algorithm goes here - it alters m_data.
       m_completed = true;
    }

    void run() const
    {
        // something that does not modify m_data or m_completed
    }
    std::vector<double> get_result() const
    {
        if (!m_completed)
            run();
        return m_data;
    }
};
```

However, that only makes sense if the `const` version of `run()` doesn't change any state.  Otherwise the non-`const`-ness of `run()` will leak into `get_result()` and make the `const`-ness of `get_result()` a blatant lie.

---

I assume that the example code is somewhat contrived.  If not, you're essentially taking this:

```
std::vector<double> results = do_calculation(data);
```

And wrapping it in an object with a very thin interface (namely, a `get_results()` method that returns the `std::vector<double>`).  I don't see much of an improvement in the object-ized version.  If you want to cache the results of your calculation, it usually makes a lot of sense to do that by simply keeping the `std::vector<double>` around int the code that would have created and used this object.

Comment: Thank you Max,  my feeling was that get_result() would normally not change anything.  I was trying to silently handle an exception.  The consensus is with you I think, with this being a bad idea.